# NoReverseMatch at /forum/

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to implement the django-registration-redux and have used templates written by Andres available at https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates . But the problem is whever i run anything i get the NoReverseMatch Error.

I tried to render the base.html template to check the error and i got error on line 12.

and the base.html is as

```
{% load i18n %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}User test{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
    {% block header %}
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a> |

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% trans "Logged in" %}: {{ user.username }} 
        (<a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a> | 
        <a href="{% url 'auth_password_change' %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>)
    {% else %}
       <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr />
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

<div id="content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="footer">
{% block footer %}
    <hr />
{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

index.html is as

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
Index page
{% endblock %}
```

and the urls.py as

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'forum'
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

and i get the error as in the below image:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc1Tp.png)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the app name in the tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'forum:index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
```